# Sign custom JRE for an Java App in macOS Catalina

Tags: java, macos, code-signing

I bundled my java application as an.app. Inside this bundle is a jre, created with jLink. (`Contents/Resources/jre/jre_11.../`) I now try to sign it with `--deep` so it signs everything recursively, but it doesn't seem to work. When I try to notarise the app, I get an error, that the bin files and dynamic libraries are not signed.

This is the command I use:

```
codesign --force --deep --timestamp --entitlements ./sign.entitlements --options runtime --sign "AppleDevIDStuff" ../../../Desktop/Launch.app/
```

- code sign doesn't give me any errors
- command `codesign -vvv --deep --strict ../../../Desktop/Launch.app/` says everything is ok
- If I try to sign `Contents/Resources/jre/jre_.../bin` I get an error, saying this directory is not a valid bundle (which is true)
- Signing the JRE as a directory for itself, outside the app, gives me the same error (Not a valid package)
- jPackage cannot be used, because it produces a different layout for `.app`, my application needs a specific layout for the contents inside `.app`.

I didn't find any guide how to sign a custom created JRE and somehow I'm unable to sign this.

So the question is basically: How to sign a custom JRE created with jLink?